# Component not rendering when testing with react-relay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, react-relay

I'm trying to test a component using React Relay and React Testing Library

```
// @flow
import { Suspense } from 'react';
import {
  RelayEnvironmentProvider,
  useLazyLoadQuery,
  graphql,
} from 'react-relay/hooks';
import { createMockEnvironment, MockPayloadGenerator } from 'relay-test-utils';
import { render, cleanup, screen, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import Banner from './Banner';
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  useLocation: jest.fn(() => ({
    pathname: 'some-path',
  })),
}));
describe('<Banner>', () => {
  let mockEnvironment;
  const defaultMockResolver = {
    // We do not want a consistent return in this case since we want the default MockPayloadGenerator behavior for most fields
    // See https://relay.dev/docs/en/testing-relay-components#mock-resolver-context
    // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
    String(context) {
      if (context.name === 'viewer') {
        return {id: 111 };
      }
    },
  };
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockEnvironment = createMockEnvironment();
  });
  afterEach(cleanup);
  it('renders - snapshot', () => {
    mockEnvironment = createMockEnvironment();
    const RelayComponent = () => {
      const data = useLazyLoadQuery(
        graphql`
          query BannerTestQuery @relay_test_operation {
            viewer {
              # Spread the fragment you want to test here
              ...Banner_viewer
            }
          }
        `,
        {},
      );
      return <Banner viewer={data.myData} />;
    };
    render(
      <RelayEnvironmentProvider environment={mockEnvironment}>
        <Suspense fallback="Loading...">
          <RelayComponent />
        </Suspense>
      </RelayEnvironmentProvider>,
    );
    // expect(container.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
    act(() => {
      mockEnvironment.mock.resolveMostRecentOperation(operation =>
        MockPayloadGenerator.generate(operation, defaultMockResolver),
      );
    });
    screen.debug();
  });
});
```

The test however does not load the component with the mocked data but only returns the Suspense fallback

Comment: Have you figured out what the issue is? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This actually works: https://githubmemory.com/repo/facebook/relay/issues/3276

It is important, that you call `queueOperationResolver` *before* rendering the component.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to add more detail here. Agree with **Tassilo Singhammer** answer. Before rendering, you need to invoke `queueOperationResolver`. Inside the `queueOperationResolver` you need to generate mock payload via `MockPayloadGenerator`. Here is the bear minimum example:

```
test('Data Render', () => {
    const environment = createMockEnvironment();

    environment.mock.queueOperationResolver((operation:any) =>
        MockPayloadGenerator.generate(operation),
      );
      
    const renderer = ReactTestRenderer.create( 
        <RelayEnvironmentProvider environment={environment}>
            <Suspense fallback={<div data-testid="loading">Loading... </div>}>
                <HelmetProvider>
                    <MemoryRouter>
                        <Home /> // Your component with the useLazyLoadQuery or a QueryRenderer
                    </MemoryRouter>
                </HelmetProvider>
            </Suspense>
      </RelayEnvironmentProvider>);

    // At this point operation will be resolved
    // and the data for a query will be available in the store
    expect(
        renderer.root.find(node => node.props['data-testid'] === 'yourButton'),
    ).toBeDefined();
  });
```

In my case, I need `HelmetProvider` and `MemoryRouter`. You may skip, if not needed.
Here is the official documentation: https://relay.dev/docs/guides/testing-relay-components/#example-with-queueoperationresolver